# Using a method of derived class through pointer to base class in C++

Tags: c++, iterator

in my program I have 2 headers (IP and MAC headers) that are 'sons' of GeneralHeader. All General, IP and MAC headers classes have PrintMe() function. In addition, I have a Packet class that holds list of GeneralHeaders (the list actually may have IP or MAC headers: (without IP defenition, to shorten):

```
//Packet.h

    class GeneralHeader {
    public:
        bool Valid;
        HeaderType_t HeaderType; // MAC or IP
        virtual void PrintMe();
    };

    class HW_MACHeader: public GeneralHeader {
    public:
        long unsigned DestAddr:48;
        long unsigned SourceAddr:48;
        virtual void PrintMe();
    };

    struct NetworkPacket_t {
        NetworkPacket_t();
        list<GeneralHeader> Headers;//TODO GeneralHeader
        void PrintMe();
    };
```

I have dificulty to implement the PrintMe() method that will print the list of GeneralHeaders using the appropriate for MAC or IP PrintMe() method (not the base PrintMe() of GeneralHeader):

```
//Packet.cpp

//This implementation prints GeneralHeaders :(
//(although MAC headers were added to the Headers list)

void NetworkPacket_t::PrintMe() {
    list<GeneralHeader>::iterator it_H;
    for (it_H = Headers.begin(); it_H != Headers.end(); ++it_H) {
        it_H->PrintMe();
    };
};
```

Another try was to cast the iterator it_H to appropriate MAC or IP header (according to HeaderType), but whichever way i tried to cast it, it did not work, e.g.:

```
//Packet.cpp
//Casting implementation
//Here I get run error: 
//terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_cast'

void NetworkPacket_t::PrintMe() {
    list<GeneralHeader>::iterator it_H;
    for (it_H = Headers.begin(); it_H != Headers.end(); ++it_H) {
        switch (it_H->HeaderType) {
        case General_Header_type:
            std::cout << " General Header " << endl;
            it_H->PrintMe();
            break;
        case MAC_Header_type:
            dynamic_cast<HW_MACHeader&>(*it_H).PrintMe();
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << " default" << endl;
        };
    };
};
```

I really appreciate any help you can prvide

Comment: You can't store derived objects in a collection that stores the base object. Read about [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you stored the `object` rather than its `pointer` into the `list`. It's something like:

```
HW_MACHeader hw;
GeneralHeader gh = hw;
```

You assign the `child object` to `parent object`, so the `gh` in the example is actually the first part of the `hw`. You could read about the [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c).

Using `pointer` is the right way:

```
HW_MACHeader hw;
GeneralHeader *gh = &hw;
```

Then when you call

```
gh->PrintMe();
```

It will call the `PrintMe` function in `HW_MACHeader`.

Take a look at this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

class GeneralHeader {
public:
    bool Valid;
    virtual void PrintMe() {cout << "General" << endl;}
};

class HW_MACHeader: public GeneralHeader {
public:
    long unsigned DestAddr;
    long unsigned SourceAddr;
    virtual void PrintMe() {cout << "HW" << endl;}
};

struct NetworkPacket_t {
    NetworkPacket_t(){}
    list<GeneralHeader *> Headers;//TODO GeneralHeader
    virtual void PrintMe();
};

void NetworkPacket_t::PrintMe() {
    list<GeneralHeader *>::iterator it_H;
    for (it_H = Headers.begin(); it_H != Headers.end(); ++it_H) {
        (*it_H)->PrintMe();
    }
}

int main()
{
    NetworkPacket_t t;
    HW_MACHeader t1;
    GeneralHeader t2;
    t.Headers.push_back(&t1);
    t.Headers.push_back(&t2);

    t.PrintMe();
    return 0;
}
```

All the assignments are replaced to `pointer` rather than `object`. The output is:

```
HW
General
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store smart pointers in the container,

```
list<shared_ptr<GeneralHeader>>
```

then virtual functions will work as intended through the pointer to the base class.